# Reading UTF-8 characters using Scanner

Tags: java, utf-8, io

```
public boolean isValid(String username, String password)  {
        boolean valid = false;
        DataInputStream file = null;

        try{
            Scanner files = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("files/students.txt")));

            while(files.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(files.next());
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

How come when I am reading a file that has been  written by UTF-8(By another java program) it displays with weird symbols followed by its String name?

```
I wrote it using this

    private static void  addAccount(String username,String password){
        File file = new File(file_name);
        try{
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file,true));
            dos.writeUTF((username+"::"+password+"\n"));
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason you use a `BufferedReader`? Also, why are you using `DataOutputStream`?

Comment: I've read that it is more efficient if I use BufferedReader

Comment: If you want to use DataInputStream you can use BufferedInputStream to improve efficiency.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a simple way to do that:

```
File words = new File(path);
Scanner s = new Scanner(words,"utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `FileReader` Javadoc:

> Convenience class for reading character files. The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are appropriate. To specify these values yourself, construct an InputStreamReader on a FileInputStream.

So perhaps something like `new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"))`

Comment: Alternatively, just use the `FileInputStream` when [constructing the `Scanner`](http://goo.gl/k5xNf), e.g. `new Scanner(new FileInputStream("files/students.txt"), "UTF-8")`

Comment: @veer I tried your code snippet. it still showing me some weird symbols

Answer (score 0):

When using [`DataOutput.writeUTF`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29)/[`DataInput.readUTF`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF%28%29), the first 2 bytes form an unsigned 16-bit big-endian integer denoting the size of the string.

> First, two bytes are read and used to construct an unsigned 16-bit integer in exactly the manner of the `readUnsignedShort` method . This integer value is called the *UTF length* and specifies the number of additional bytes to be read. These bytes are then converted to characters by considering them in groups. The length of each group is computed from the value of the first byte of the group. The byte following a group, if any, is the first byte of the next group.

These are likely the cause for your issues. You'd need to skip the first 2 bytes and then specify your `Scanner` use UTF-8 to read properly.

That being said, I do not see any reason to use `DataOutput`/`DataInput` here. You can merely use `FileReader` and `FileWriter` instead. These will use the default system encoding.

Comment: How would I declare that in the scanner. I tried this  Scanner files = new Scanner(new FileReader("accnts.txt"), "UTF-8"); but it gave me an error

Comment: @user962206 there are no such constructors that take `FileReader` followed by `String` denoting the character encoding. There is however [one using `File`](http://goo.gl/MJPYU), [one using `InputStream`](http://goo.gl/1Hd5d), and lastly [one using `ReadableByteChannel`](http://goo.gl/1m2WJ).

Comment: how would I instantiate i am kinda confused.

Comment: @user962206 if you *really* wish for this to work while retaining your use of `DataOutput`, I'd try the following: http://pastie.org/private/06wqqq83mklkw86wmdz6g.