# Java, calculating difference between unique characters in strings

Tags: java, string

Let's say I have 2 strings and i need to calculate a difference between their unique characters. It's simple:

```
String s1 = "abcd";
String s2 = "aaaacccbbf";
//answer: 1
```

The answer is 1, because there is no "f" in s1 variable.

But what about characters like மா or 漢字, or any other non ASCII character? If i loop though those strings, one character like கு will count 2-3 times as separate character, giving me wrong answer:

```
String s1 = "ab";
String s2 = "aaaகுb";
//answer: 2 (wrong!)
```

The code i tried with:

```
class a {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1 = sc.nextLine();
        String s2 = sc.nextLine();
        sc.close();

        String missingCharacters= "";

        for(char c : s2.toCharArray()) {
            if(!missingCharacters.contains(c+"") && !s1.contains(c+"")) 
                missingCharacters+= c;
        }

        System.out.println(missingCharacters.length());
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the கு is unicode character, and toCharArray gives you individual bytes. Look if you can't set encoding somewhere.

Comment: I just ran your code on my machine and got 1 for `ab` vs `aaaகுb`.

Comment: The answer to this is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963563/reading-utf-8-characters-using-scanner

Comment: Your code works fine with `漢字மா ` and other characters except கு

Comment: Also, it doesn't work with arabic characters: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet)(counts as 2), and whitespace characters(spacebar, tab) which are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your symbol `கு` is compound form of Tamil script which contains two Unicode chars `க் + உ` (0B95 + 0BC1). If you plan to work with Tamil script you have to find all similiar characters with pattern:

```
    String s1 = "ab";
    String s2 = "aaaகுb";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{L}\\p{M}*");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s2);
    Set<String> missingCharacters=new TreeSet<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        missingCharacters.add(matcher.group());
    }

    matcher = pattern.matcher(s1);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        missingCharacters.remove(matcher.group());
    }

    System.out.println(missingCharacters.size());
```

Regex source:
[How to Match a Single Unicode Grapheme](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#grapheme)

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, I'm not working only with Tamil script. Do you know any other unicode characters (with solution for them) which may cause same issue?

Comment: Example: `Thîs lóo̰ks we̐ird` works fine with my solution and not works with your code.

Comment: I've tested your code in some examples, and it doesn't work with "க்ஷௌ" character.

Answer (score 0):

கு is a special character, it it formed by merging க and ு, thus creating 2 different characters, and doesn't have 1 single `char` value. You are looping over the `char`s in `s2`, so you won't find that character itself.

Java doesn't have a way around this, as `String.substring()` and `String.charAt()` both use `char`s.

Conclusion, it's impossible to do this with Java's default libraries.

Comment: I'd like to get feedback according to that down-vote.

Comment: "It's impossible with Java" is silly; Java's Turing-complete. You might need specialized libraries to recognize that the characters get stuck together, but that doesn't make it _impossible._

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<Integer> missing = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < s1.length();) {
  int codePoint = s1.codePointAt(i);
  if (s2.indexOf(codePoint) == -1) {
    missing.add(codePoint); // takes care of duplicates
  }
  i += Character.charCount(codePoint);
}
System.out.println(missing.size());
```

Comment: You should either remove the `{` after `if (s2...` or add a `}` above `i +=...`

Comment: I tried to run your code with `String s1="ab", s2 = "aaaகுb"`, but it gives an output of `0`. A quick debug after `int codePoint` gives only the values 97 and 98 (`a` and `b`), but skips the special character. (Using Java 1.7)

Comment: with `String s2="ab"`, `s1 = "aaaகுb"` it gives `2`, not `1`

Comment: @RuslanOstafiychuk What Java-version are you using ?

Comment: @Charlie, jdk1.7_71
but I just said that answer is wrong :)

Comment: Yes, I switched `s1` and `s2`.  I'm not sure, though: that character definitely appears to translate into two distinct code points, _not_ one split code point.  It's not clear to me how that should be counted, or in what sense it actually is one "character."

Comment: When I examine the string in the debugger, that original symbol becomes two distinct characters: `க ு`.

Comment: I would like to pass your code on ide.com, but your code is giving wrong answer there (switched s1 with s2): [link](http://ideone.com/ytilpY)

Comment: @user3058763: That's the content of my discussion with Charlie.